# New Stack Exchange site proposal: Computational Fluid Dynamics!

Tags: discussion, sponsorship-and-advertising, related-stack-exchange-sites

There's a proposal at the moment for creating an SE site for computational fluid dynamics, and if you would like SE to add a site for this topic, I suggest you follow the proposal, ask some example questions and ***upvote five questions*** because the biggest barrier for getting past the first stage in the site-creation proposal process, is to get 40 questions with 10 upvotes each. You can support the proposal by clicking the orange button below:

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Computational Fluid Dynamics]

Or if you have a browser that blocks dynamic images, then you can click on [this link](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/124777/computational-fluid-dynamics?referrer=NDEwM2Y5ZDUwMWM4ZGJlNjI3Mzk5ZTE0NjQxNGU2ZTlhNjhiNGE2YWU3ZjdmNjM2NWZmYWM2NWZmYjAwOWJhMjR2WfTKgQz5xXEn59aXykYURxr01Fepmvk4JXcWA5yn0). **You have to first click "sign-up" on Area51, not "log-in", before clicking "follow" (please let us know in the comments if it doesn't work!).**

While it might seem like this site is "competing" with MMSE in some sense, I still think it would be valuable for ***our site*** to support this proposal. This is because if the CFD site becomes a success, even more computational physical scientists will join SE and we'll get more members here too. If the proposal fails, then most of the supporters will likely join MMSE as the best alternative, and the closer the proposal gets to succeeding, the more users we will have coming this way. It's a win-win situation.

Comment: Astronomy SE and Space Exploration SE might be a good model in that while there is some overlap between the fields there's also some overlap in their communities who seem to do well keeping things sorted out between the two, and I do think that the two sites feed into each other new member-wise and so "cast a larger net".

Comment: @uhoh But Area51 has the bug with the email addresses, so it's extremely hard to get a new site launched now, unless someone spends hundreds of hours asking people to sign up and helping them get passed that bug!

Comment: as I [painfully remember](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29825/205305) @@